# Facebook, write on application wall

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've been using the Facebook C# SDK for 5 months but suddenly I started getting problems with writing on my Application wall yesterday night. To clarify, I'm not writing on the users wall. Only on the application wall.

This is the code:

```
string facebookmessage = "Testmessage";

var appAccessToken = "App_id|App_secret";

try
{
    var fb2 = new FacebookClient(appAccessToken);
    dynamic result = fb2.Post("/App_id/feed", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "message", facebookmessage } });
}
catch (Exception ea)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(ea.Message);
}
```

This worked as a charm until yesterday. The App posted the text on it's own wall as this picture shows

[http://www.veikontroller.no/veikontroll_screen.png](http://192.168.1.36/veikontroll_screen.png)

This stopped working and is now giving me this error message:

```
(OAuthException) (#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories
```

I've tried to replace App_secret with the Access Token from the App developer page. This works, but the result is a post from my user on the application wall, and I don't want to display my name on the posts. If I write a post manually on the app wall in a browser on facebook.com my user is substituted with the app name a second after I have posted.

Does anyone know of changes that has been made by Facebook that may be the reason?

Best regards
Øystein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure the specifics of the C# API, but in general, check out the 'accounts' connection on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

So

1. Generate an access token for a user with the manage_pages permission
2. Call https://graph.facebook.com/{uid}/accounts..which will return all the apps/pages that the user is an admin of along with access tokens that allow you to behave as the app/page
3. Use that access token and attempt to write on the wall of the app...

Comment: Thank you very much! I had some troubles getting the access token with manage_pages permission. I got API error 191. The website URL was not set properly in the Application settings. I set it to https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APP_ID. Once I got the new token it all worked as it did a couple of days ago.